# Displaying data from two tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, join, eloquent

I'm learning Laravel and have an issue I really can't resolve despite hours of googling. I have three tables - projects, users and project managers. I am trying to create a drop down list in the projects edit.blade that will display the name of the project manager by joining up the user_id from the project manager table to the id of the users table, however I obviously want the PM_ID to be saved when the user chooses a name. I tried creating a join in the edit method of my controller but I am not having any luck. I have set up all my relationships in the model also, I think that they are correct? Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

My table set up is as follows (I left irrelevant fields out):

```
    Projects:
       ID, 
       Name, 
       PM_ID

    Users:
       ID, 
       Name

   Project Managers:
      ID, 
      User_ID
```

Project Controller:

```
    $project_managers = DB::table('project_managers')
       ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'project_managers.user_id')
       ->select('users.name', 'project_managers.id')
       ->lists('users.name', 'project.managers.id')
       ->get();

   return view('admin.projects.edit', compact('project', 'project_managers'));
```

edit.blade:

```
    <div class="form-group">{!! Form::label('PM_id', 'Project Manager:') !!}{!! Form::select('PM_id', ['' => 'Choose a PM'], $project_managers, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>
```

My relationships are:

Project:

```
    public function project_manager(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\ProjectManager');
    }
```

ProjectManager:

```
    public function user(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
     }
```

User:

```
    public function project_manager(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\ProjectManager');
     }
```

With this code I am getting the following error:

```
      FatalThrowableError in AdminProjectsController.php line 97: Call to a member function get() on array
```

Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `lists();` isn't a method I use massively but the docs say it returns an array so the `get()` wouldn't be needed?
From here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects

`$roles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title');`
"This method will return an array of role titles. You may also specify a custom key column for the returned array:"

Also, if you've set the relationships through the model like you have, you could use eloquent to get the related records? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Laravel do the heavy lifting using the relationships you've set up.

```
$project_managers = \App\ProjectManager::with('user')->get();
$pms = [];
foreach($project_managers as $pm){
    $pms[$pm->id] = $pm->user->name;
}
```

You can send `$pms` to the view and the dropdown should work for you.  If the relationship was one to many, you could use the `pluck()` function, but I think a simple loop after the db pull will do what you need here.